# How to restore an item deleted from Realm?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I'm creating a RecyclerView with swipe-to-delete feature, but I have no idea about how to support **undo** operation.

My database is Realm. When I need to delete an item, I use:

```
item.deleteFromRealm()
```

and append the item in an undoList, when I need to restore it, I use:

```
realm.insert(undoList.last())
```

but I discovered it is an invalid object.

I know that the saved item became invalid when I deleted it.

So how can I accomplish the undo feature?

Comment: You can't. Only way is that instead of actually deleting the item, you set a boolean flag to true instead. Or have an unmanaged copy that you re-insert for undo. But deletion invalidates links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply *not* delete the object from Realm, or at least, not for now.

One idea is to add to that object a custom field, something along the lines of `boolean askedForDeletion;` (and its setter and getter).

Then, when you want to delete it, you will just turn this field to false, add it to the undo list, and ask the RecyclerView to reload:

```
item.setAskedForDeletion(false); 
undoList.add(item);
recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now, of course, the `RecyclerView`'s dataset has to filter the items according to that variable. Somewhere in the code you ask to Realm to give you the items. If you have something like:

```
realm.where([Item].class).findAll();
```

then you should update it with:

```
realm.where([Item].class).equalTo("askedForDeletion", false).findAll();
```

So that you get only the non-deleted.

Finally: decide a moment in which the app should delete the "undo list". Maybe "onDestroy", or somewhere where you are confident that the user will not be sad to be unable to not undo anymore. There, you should delete all the items that asked for deletion:

```
realm.where([Item].class).equalTo("askedForDeletion", true).findAll(); // And delete them as you prefer.
```

Comment: Simple but efficient solution. I have accomplish that. Thanks you very much.

Comment: P.S. I realized that a **trash can** can be created in this way, which means that we can actually delete the items when user clear the can